# I have some problems in timing in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python from the book
[https://www.amazon.com/Learning-Python-5th-Mark-Lutz/dp/1449355730](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449355730)
and I have some problems in chapter 21 that is about timing in python

this book has given this module to get operation time of functions :

```
"""
homegrown timing tools for function calls.
Does the total-time, best-of-time, and best of totals time.
"""
import time , sys 
timer = time.perf_counter

def total(reps , func , *pargs , **kargs) :
    replist = list(range(reps))
    start   = timer() 
    for i in replist :
        ret = func(*pargs , **kargs) 
    
    elapsed = timer() - start 
    return (elapsed , ret) 


def bestof (reps , func , *pargs , **kargs) :
    best = 2 ** 32 
    for i in range(reps) :
        start = timer()
        ret = func(*pargs , **kargs) 
        elapsed = timer() - start  
        if elapsed < best : best = elapsed 
    
    return (best , ret)



def bestoftotal(reps1 ,reps2 , func , *pargs , **kargs ) :
    return bestof(reps1 , total , reps2  , func , *pargs , **kargs)
```

the first function gives us the total time of a function when we call it 1000 times
the second one calculates the time of each 1000 time operation and gives the best one
and the third one gives the best of totals, mean that calculates totals and gives the best one (min time ), my problem here is exactly in the third one.
in the main program I'm trying to run it and please look at the output :

```
import timer 
A= timer.bestoftotal(1000 , 1000 , pow , 2 , 1000)
print('pow best totals : ' ,A[0]  , A[1][0])
```

and this is my output

```
PS C:\Users\Ata Barzegar\Desktop\learn> & "C:/Users/Ata Barzegar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe" "c:/Users/Ata Barzegar/Desktop/learn/learnpy.py"
pow best totals :  0.0011224999999999152       0.001119799999999893
```

the problem is that we are trying to get the minimum time of total  but the second number is smaller than the first one,plz help me
Also, I should mention this does not happen every time.

Comment: Your last paragraph is not clear. Please could you explain what the output should be? Is it the total time, the average and the best(shortest)?

Answer (score 0):

```
def bestof(reps, func, *pargs, **kargs):
    best = 2 ** 32
    best_ret = None
    for i in range(reps):
        start = timer()
        ret = func(*pargs, **kargs)
        elapsed = timer() - start
        if elapsed < best:
            best = elapsed
            best_ret = ret
    return (best, best_ret)
```

in `bestof` function, you always return the last `ret`. So, if you want to compare those two timings, you should declare a `best_ret` and return it

Comment: Hi dear Mehdi 
this is not what I really want to know 
my question is about that we are trying to get the best of totals with its function that returns best of function with argument of total function 
so the A parameter has a form like this   A = ( a , ( b , c ) )  and my question is that a will gives us the fastest total and b will give us the last total as you told . why b is smaller than a  . I hope this will help you to know my main problem